# Is it possible to play the community levels of LittleBigPlanet 1 in LittleBigPlanet 2?

Tags: little-big-planet, little-big-planet-2

I would like to know if the community levels of LittleBigPlanet 1 are also available in LittleBigPlanet 2.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes LBP1 levels can be played in LBP2. When doing a search for levels you can even choose to only search for LBP1 levels (or only LBP2 levels as well).

Answer (score 7):

Yes, LBP2 is fully backwards compatible, so you can play any of the previous levels in the new game.